# How to login to winauth application using python selenium?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I am using "winauth" app and I need to write a login script using python selenium.

How can I achieve this?

Please find the image of the app

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use autoit to automate any desktop application. 1st thing is you can remove all extra protection by going to "settings ->change protection -> deselect all authentication" or you need to write code for every step using autoit.
Below is sample code to automate winauth:

```
import autoit
from autoit.autoit import AutoItError
try:
    # right click to copy code. To get the mouse position at refresh button by using autoit tool.
    autoit.mouse_click(button='right', x=1482, y=94) 
    # configure shortcut keys to copy key on clipboard 
    #(shortcut keys... -> Key -> F2 (or any other key) 
    #and select 'copy code to clipboard')
    autoit.send('{F2}')
    token = autoit.clip_get()
    print(f"Success: {token}")
except AutoItError:
    print("failed!!")
```